# Ionic Native File Plugin - Checking Directory's Existence Not Working

Tags: javascript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

im trying out some ionic native plugins, so far everything has been great excpet for the file plugin.
I've been trying to create directory in the externalDataDirectory path provided by the file plugin.
What am trying to do is check if the directory exists first but that actually seems to be the issue.
Here is my code.

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';

export class MyClass {

    constructor(private file: File, private filePath: FilePath) {}

    createDirectory(onSuccess?: (val: any) => any, onError?: (err: any) => any) {
    // root_dir = this.file.externalDataDirectory
    this.filePath.resolveNativePath(this.root_dir).then(
      (nativePath) => {
        this.file.checkDir(nativePath, 'myDir').then(
          (exists) => {
            if (!exists) {
              this.file.createDir(nativePath, 'myDir', false).then(
                (dirEntry) => {
                  onSuccess(dirEntry);
                },
                (err) => {
                  console.log('CreateDir error: ' + err);
                  onError(err);
                }
              ).catch( (exception) => { console.log(exception); } );
            }
            else {
              return nativePath + 'myDir';
            }
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log('CheckDir error: ' + err);
            onError(err);
          }
        ).catch( (exception) => { console.log(exception); } );
      },
      (err) => {
       // error occurs here.
        onError(err);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

I dont know what im doing wrong, can anyone be of assistance. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please post the error that you are getting?

Comment: Am getting an ENCODING_ERROR

Comment: Looks like your error is caused by the line `this.filePath.resolveNativePath(...)`. Can you please confirm this? If true, can you please verify the value of  `this.root_dir`?

Comment: The value of root_dir = file:///storage/sdcard0/android/data/com.ionicframework.myApp537218

Comment: According to [the docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#list-of-error-codes-and-meanings) ENCODING_ERROR is from File Plugin (and not File Path Plugin). So your error is in the line `this.file.createDir` or `this.file.checkDir`. Please inform the parameters value passed to these functions.